# Highcharts conditional data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a Highcharts line chart based upon some user input. The user can select 1 or more groupings and a date range and I create a series for each group. This works fine except for that when they select over 3 groups, the chart looks terrible because there are way too many data labels.

I'd like to conditionally enable data labels only when where are less than 4 series on a chart. How can I do that? I'm trying like this but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: function() {
                return !!(chart.series.length > 3);
            },
            color: '#000000',
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the series before the chart is created ?

Comment: Yes. I'm creating all the series and then passing the entirely formatted series dictionary to the Javascript like                 },
                series: {{ classes_data|safe }}
            });

Comment: Which means I can do this on the back end, but was curious as to how to do this in Javascript.

Comment: I've posted a answer which assumed you were generating in javascript. Similar thing applies in the back end.

Comment: You may be able to do it in javascript, depending on what the server is returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the series, keep track of how many you create. Also have a javascript variable 'showDataLabels=true'. If the number of series goes above 4 when you are creating them, set showDataLabels=false;

```
var showDataLabels = true;
// start creating the series.
```

If num series > 4
       showDataLabels = false;

Once you are ready to generate the chart, use:

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled:showDataLabels,
                    color: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something like this on the back end.

Answer (score -1):

Use Formatter fucntion in dataLables

```
formatter: function ()  {
    if(this.y!=0)
        return this.y;
    else`enter code here`
        return "";
}
```